# Archiving custom element types

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I am building a custom element type and want to have the ability to archive entries. I can create a custom status for 'archived' but I've noticed base elements already have an 'archived' status I could use. Is it wise to do this? I don't know if Craft will delete elements marked as 'archived' after a period?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is to roll my own archiving method – archived elements results in them not being accessible in element indexes.

Comment: Not really an answer, but there is a feature request for this, please upvote to increase the chances of it being addressed in a future update:
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4223